# Concatenate string in C

Tags: c, string, concatenation

Im trying to the java equivalant of something like 
str = "stuff " + str;

I tried using sprintf(str, "stuff %s", str); and str = strcat("Stuff ", str); 
None of this as worked... am I forced to use a second string to save the result?

Something like sprintf(str2, "stuff %s", str) or str2 = strcat("Stuff ", str);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation. The correct form for `strcat is`

```
strcat(char* destination, const char* source);
```

which will append `source` to `destination`. Your way was backwards - and since `"Stuff"` is a `const char*`, it would fail.

```
strcat(str, "Stuff");
```

should work, resulting in `str` containing the original string, followed by `Stuff`.

Example:

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char string[256];
  char s2[256];
  strcpy(string, "hello ");
  strcat(string, "world");
  printf("The concatenated string is '%s'\n", string);
  sprintf(string, "I say %s", string);
  printf("The new string is '%s\n'", string);
  strcpy(string, "hello world");
  sprintf(s2, "I say %s", string);
  printf("And now it is '%s'\n", s2);
}
```

Results in

```
The concatenated string is 'hello world'
The new string is 'I say I say world
'And now it is 'I say hello world'
```

As you can see, you need to place the result of the `sprintf` in a different string, or things will overwrite (by the time the compiler gets to reading `string` into the format string, it has been overwritten…)

I think there is no way around creating a copy of the string to do what you are after - prepending a string constant. Some languages just spoil you...

Comment: But if I use strcat(str, "stuff  ); I will get the opposite result, (str = str + "Stuff ") right? how can I get str = "stuff " + str;? I supose I can't use strcat without passing stuff to a string

Answer (score 0):

It is actually better to use a second string.

But, if you really don't want to and you are sure to have enough allocated space into your variable. Then you can do the following

`strncpy(memmove(str + 6, str, strlen(str) + 1) - 6, "stuff ", 6); //+ 1 to copy the null character`

Or

```
memmove(str + 6, str, strlen(str) + 1);
strncpy(str, "stuff ", 6);
```

Even if this solution works, I would not recommend you to use it. It is less readable and - I think - slower.

If you are using malloc and need realloc. You have no issue since reallocating a bigger chunk of memory gives a new undetermined value.